# Sharepoint spfx, onListViewUpdated() async

Tags: sharepoint, spfx

I need to implement a button in a ListView Command Set extension that is only visible if the user has edit permissions for the selected item in a list. Therefore I have to make an async api call in the onListViewUpdated() method, but I does not seem to work, because onListViewUpdated() cannot be used as a aync function. Does anyone have a solution to that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [thread](https://www.eliostruyf.com/showing-or-hiding-sharepoint-framework-listview-custom-actions-based-on-permissions-and-selected-items/).

```
@override
public onListViewUpdated(event: IListViewCommandSetListViewUpdatedParameters): void {
  // Get commands
  const commandOne: Command = this.tryGetCommand('COMMAND_1');
  const commandTwo: Command = this.tryGetCommand('COMMAND_2');

  // Command checks
  if (commandOne) {
    this._hideCommandByPermissionSet(commandOne, SPPermission.editListItems);
  }
  if (commandTwo) {
    this._hideCommandByPermissionSet(commandTwo, SPPermission.approveItems);
  }
}

private _hideCommandByPermissionSet(crntCommand: Command, permission: SPPermission) {
  if (this.context.pageContext.list.permissions.hasPermission(permission)) {
    crntCommand.visible = true;
  } else {
    crntCommand.visible = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Lee_MSFT I already checked and commented that thread (check the latest comment ;-) ) . In your example and in the thread, list permissions are checked, but not the permissions of an item in the list. Those are two different things and I need to check if the user has edit permission of certains items in a list.